# Create Large File in /dev/shm in parallel: performance

Tags: c, filesystems, ramdisk

I need to create a large file (several gbytes) in /dev/shm. which is a RAMdisk on Linux machines.  This must be as fast as possible.  I'm currently using 5 separate POSIX threads in C to create sequential 100 mbyte segments, then I have another thread which concatenates them onto the main output file.

This is fast, but I want to go faster.  Can I eliminate the concatenate thread?  Is there any way to open a file, and have each thread write it's 100 mbyte segment to the correct place in the final output file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way to do this is to just call `truncate()` or `ftruncate()` to expand the file to the size you want.

You can then `mmap()` the file into the process's memory space, and have each thread write its section into the mapped area.

Comment: I tried this, and it might work.  But I was able to 'create' files that were larger than the filesystem that contained them.  Somehow, that doesn't seem right.

Comment: So the basic idea is this: First, use truncate to create the huge file, then each thread uses lseek() to move forward to its spot in the file, then that thread writes the data there?  Is that right?

Comment: Okay.  mmap().  Hadn't thought of this.

Comment: `truncate` is not needed. `lseek` alone will do the job just fine.

Comment: Well, `truncate` is needed for the `mmap` approach, but not for `write`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply open the file once for each thread, `lseek` to the position the thread is suppose to start at, and `write` normally. Or, you could use `pwrite` to specify the location of the write; in that case, a single open could be shared by all the threads since they don't need to use the current file position.

If you want to ensure in advance that there's space available and reserved for the entire final file, `posix_fallocate` should be able to take care of that for you.